# JBOSS 5 run.conf Variables

Tags: jboss5.x

In my run.conf file I want to pass in the directory into which jboss is installed as an application variable... so for instance if JBOSS is installed at: /opt/jboss-5.1.0-GA/ I want to pass in:

```
-Dmyvar=${path above}
```

But, I want JBOSS to automatically fill in ${path above} with /opt/jboss-5.1.0-GA.

I can't count on the JBOSS_HOME environment variable to be set.

I tried to look this up on The Google, but I didn't exactly know how to word it.

Thanks

Comment: If you cant count on JBOSS_HOME, then you will have to explicitly set the variable in run.conf

Comment: Thanks... I figured that was the case...

Comment: I have added that as an answer. Please mark that as right one, if it is right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cant count on `JBOSS_HOME`, then you will have to explicitly set the variable in `run.conf`